# How to decrease the EBS Volumes size in EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I've updated the EC2 volumes size recently, now i no longer needed the extra size.

AWS didn't provide an option to decrease the Volume size.

I'm thinking of doing it using Backup the volume data to s3 and import data in new instance with reduced volume size attached.

Comment: The only benefit in decreasing the size is a cost saving of around 8c/GB/month (~ $1/GB/year). Is it really worth your time for the amount you'll save?

Answer (score 1):

we can follow [this](https://medium.com/@m.yunan.helmy/decrease-the-size-of-ebs-volume-in-your-ec2-instance-ea326e951bce) article to decrease the ec2 attached volume size.

Steps:

- Create new volume with desired size.
- Attach new volume to ec2 instance.
- Copy data from old_volume to new_volume.
- detach old volume.

Comment: It other words, its not possible to decrease volume size. Instead have to copy all data to new, smaller volume.